# Qt-GStreamer: PKGCONFIG not found

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gstreamer

I am pretty new to setting the Qt Creator environment in Linux.
I will cross compile this demo program to the Yocto Project i.MX6.  This demo program needs to use Qt-GStreamer

in `demo.pro`
There is these 2 lines

`CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG +=  Qt5GLib-2.0 Qt5GStreamer-1.0 Qt5GStreamerUi-1.0 Qt5GStreamerUtils-1.0 Qt5GStreamerQuick-1.0`

at compile in the Desktop, it shows
`error: Qt5GLib-2.0 development package not found`
This applies to all the other packages as well.

I know that it tells me that I am missing the package for the Qt Gstreamer.

However, when I look at this [thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/error-package-qt5gstreamer-0-10-not-found-4175492115/), the answer is

`export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/home/anisha/Desktop/newGSTr/qt-gstreamer-0.10.3/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig`

But, from what I have downloaded in [Qt Binding-GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/qt-gstreamer.html) `qt-gstreamer-0.10.3` Does not have the lib folder inside.

I have also used cmake to work with the CMakeList.txt inside the folder but encounter Qt missing packages error.

Could someone help me on setting up those packages?

Comment: "*I know that it tells me that I am missing the package for the Qt Gstreamer.*" How exactly does it tell you that? Please include the exact error message in the question.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited it.

Comment: Greetings! Don't use GStreamer version 0.10, use 1.x.

Comment: Use Qt Creator and qtgstreamer from your distribution official repos using standard package manager, don't build from source / download from website.

Comment: What OS do you use? Ubuntu? Fedora?

Comment: I am trying to cross compile to the WandBoard Quad.  The thing is, I am in the Yocto Daisy branch and they have an incomplete version of GStreamer1.0. so I am stuck with 0.10.  I can try to work with 1.0 and update to Jethro.
The host is Ubuntu 14.04.  I downloaded qt5.5 from the Qt page though.  How do I get a standard package for GStreamer? I do not have a distribution official repos other than Yocto.